# Sum Query in Elasticsearch

Tags: nosql, elasticsearch

I'm fairly new to Elasticsearch.  I'm trying to write a query that will group by a field and calculate a sum.  In SQL, my query would look like this:
`SELECT lane, SUM(routes) FROM lanes GROUP BY lane`

I have this data that looks like this in ES:

```
{
  "_index": "kpi",
  "_type": "mroutes_by_lane",
  "_id": "TUeWFEhnS9q1Ukb2QdZABg",
  "_score": 1.0,
  "_source": {
    "warehouse_id": 107,
    "date": "2013-04-08",
    "lane": "M05",
    "routes": 4047
  }
},
{
  "_index": "kpi",
  "_type": "mroutes_by_lane",
  "_id": "owVmGW9GT562_2Alfru2DA",
  "_score": 1.0,
  "_source": {
    "warehouse_id": 107,
    "date": "2013-04-08",
    "lane": "M03",
    "routes": 4065
  }
},
{
  "_index": "kpi",
  "_type": "mroutes_by_lane",
  "_id": "JY9xNDxqSsajw76oMC2gxA",
  "_score": 1.0,
  "_source": {
    "warehouse_id": 107,
    "date": "2013-04-08",
    "lane": "M05",
    "routes": 3056
  }
},
{
  "_index": "kpi",
  "_type": "mroutes_by_lane",
  "_id": "owVmGW9GT345_2Alfru2DB",
  "_score": 1.0,
  "_source": {
    "warehouse_id": 107,
    "date": "2013-04-08",
    "lane": "M03",
    "routes": 5675
  }
},
...
```

I want to essentially run the same query in ES as I did in SQL, so that my result would be something like (in json of course): `M05: 7103, M03: 9740`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In elasticsearch, you can achieve this by using [terms stats facet](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/terms-stats-facet/):

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {  }
    },
    "facets" : {
        "lane_routes_stats" : {
            "terms_stats" : {
                "key_field" : "lane",
                "value_field" : "routes",
                "order": "term"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks imotov. How do I sort the stat results? I'd like to sort by lane field, which is `facets.lane_routes_stats.terms.term`

Comment: All sort options are described in the documentation that I linked in my answer. I have also updated the answer with an example.